# Django query set variable of type None

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have to run a code to get list of matching tags from car model

```
for tag_list in tag_id_list:
    car_filter = (car_filter | car.filter(tag_in=[tag_list]) ).distinct()
```

In the above code car is of type <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
How do I declare variable **car_filter of type <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>** to do the union of the **car_filter and car**

Tried with  `car_filter = None  and <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>None`

Comment: We can not, But what can we do is make 2nd one set like this set(car.filter(tag_in=[tag_list]))

Comment: Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: We can replace the line with `car_filter = (car_filter | set(car.filter(tag_in=[tag_list])) ).distinct()`

Comment: Note: using `set` is evaluated in Python and not in the database so it might have some performance hit.

Comment: just wondering what is the inital value of car_filter when using in the above code

Answer (score 0):

Filtered the whole list at once instead of individual itertions

```
car = car.filter(tag_in=[tag_id_list]) ).distinct()
```